# Understanding proof for unordered triples in Halmos's Naive Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

On page 14 of Halmos's *Naive Set Theory*, he states the following. For context, I'm going to include the entire paragraph up to the point of confusion.

> An equally simple but quite suggestive fact is that
> $$ 
> \{a\} \cup \{b\} = \{a,b\}. 
> $$
> What this suggests is the way to generalize pairs. Specifically, we write
> $$ 
> \{a,b,c\} = \{a\} \cup \{b\} \cup \{c\}. 
> $$
> The equation defines its left side. The right side should by rights have at least one pair of parentheses in it, but in view of the associative law, their omission can lead to no misunderstanding. Since it is easy to prove that
> $$ 
> \{a,b,c\} = \{x : x = a \text{ or } x = b \text{ or } x = c\},
> $$
> we know now that for every three sets there exists a set that contains the and nothing else; it is natural to call that uniquely determined set the unordered triple formed by them.

I have one question and one point of confusion.

1. I'm confused by the statement that Halmos says is "easy to prove." It could just be that, having worked with sets in a less formal setting than Halmos' book, this fact just seems "obvious" to me to the point where I want to say, "the right-hand side is the definition," but that is surely insufficient here. I think he wants me to use the definition o a triple. In particular, I think he wants me to write
   $$
   \{a,b,c\} = \{a\} \cup \{b\} \cup \{c\}. 
   $$
   Then I think I can use the "definition" of union for a collection of sets $\mathcal{C}$, with $\mathcal{C}$ equal to the three sets on right-hand side. That definition says exactly that the union over these three sets is equal to the set of $x$ that lives in at least one of them, which is what the right-hand side says.

Is this a fully rigorous proof, or did Halmos have something else in mind?

2. When Halmos writes down a set in the form $\{x : P(x)\}$, what should I take the "large" set to which $x$ belongs to be? There is no "set of all sets," but I think we often define a "universe" to be a large set with the property that every set of interest is a subset thereof. Such a set is not mentioned, so should I just take it as "assumed" or "arbitrary"? I'd want to write a set in the form, say,
   $$
   \{x \in \mathbb{R} : P(x)\},
   $$
   where $\mathbb{R}$ is just one example and could be replaced with, say, $\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: For \#2: I don’t know whether this helps, but I’ve been thinking of “$\{x\in\Bbb R\colon P(x)\}$” as a shorthand for “$\{x:(x\in\Bbb R)\Rightarrow\bigl(P(x)\bigr)\}$”.

Comment: @Lubin Is there a reason it wouldn't be $\{x : x \in \mathbb{R} \wedge P(x)\}$?

Comment: This is getting too deep for me, but $P(x)$ might be meaningless or ungrammatical if $x$ was not in $\Bbb R$, so that your formulation would not be well-formed. (I think.) Perhaps my attitude is formed by my experience with programming, where some parsers would object to your formulation,if $P(x)$ didn’t have universal applicability. (sorry for the nontechnical language, professional coders)

Comment: @Lubin Your first comment is wrong, John T is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need a universe if your $P(x)$ establishes a comparison, as in your example $x<5$. But many $P(x)$ are not like that, starting from the one in your question. If I write
$$
A=\{x: x=1\ \text{or}\ x=3\},
$$
then it is clear that $A=\{1,3\}$. If a universe is needed, nothing prevents you from establishing it in $P$. For instance, you could have $$P(x)=\{x\in\mathbb R\ \text{ and }x<5\}$$
and then $\{x:\ P (x)\}$ has no ambiguity.

Comment: Set theoretically speaking one does not need a universe even in that case. [since $<$ is a relation, and hence a set]. But naively if one does not know that, I suppose that this answer is OK. In fact formal set theory does not allow you to “form partitions” like this, $\forall x$ ranges over all sets always.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, Halmos probably wants to you to prove that $$a\in\{x : x = a \text{ or } x = b \text{ or } x = c\}\iff a\in [ \{a\}\cup\{b\}\cup\{c\}]$$For all $a$ and hence conclude that the two sets  are equal, this can be done quite easily by using the definition of a union. 
For your second question I’m not quite sure what your issue is, but note that the **axiom of union** guarantees the existence of the union set, so we **aren’t** doing any universal comprehension.

Comment: The issue I'm having with the second question is that it's my understanding that when a set is specified by a condition, I need to look at "the set of $x$ in some large set" and see whether they possess some property, but this definition doesn't tell me where those $x$ belong.

Comment: @JohnT Why do you need to look at some larger set?

Comment: Well, what if the set I wrote down was $\{x : x < 5\}$? If I don't know whether the "universal" set is $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{R}$, I can't write down the set.